# How to convert a multi line string into a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, converters, multiline

I have this design, for example:

```
design = """xxx
yxx
xyx"""
```

And I would like to convert it to an array, a matrix, nested lists, like this:

```
[['x', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'x']]
```

How would you do this, please?

Comment: If you really want it to act like an array, rather than a list of lists (hard to index columns) then you should put it into a Numpy `array`.

Comment: are the x's and y's meant to be variable names or 1 letter strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `str.splitlines` with either `map` or a `list comprehension`:

Using `map`:

```
>>> map(list, design.splitlines())
[['x', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'x']]
```

List Comprehension:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in  design.splitlines()]
[['x', 'x', 'x'], ['y', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'y', 'x']]
```